# How to transcode AES encrypted files with AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, openssl, cryptography

I want to upload my encrypted videos to S3 and use Elastic Transcoder to transcode them. This is what I'm currently doing and isn't working at all. I'm using `openssl` to encrypt my video files. The commands I'm using are:

```
PASSWORD=$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c16)
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$PASSWORD -p -in VIDEO.mkv -out VIDEO.enc.mkv
```

This echo's out my salt, key and IV in `hex`:

```
salt=BBE61C94DD1B3395
key=03A4C8AB06A09C924947FC865415FE58E1AFC6C998FA7CA8B9DE8E5C232CE0E9
iv =9325C43C36A7868957613EF80FEED569
```

I then upload that encrypted file to S3 using the `aws s3` command line utility.

AWS Elastic Transcoder tells me:

```
Decryption Key: The Base64 encoded encrypted key that you want Elastic Transcoder to use to decrypt the input.
Decryption Key MD5: The Base64 encoded MD5 digest of the encrypted key that you want Elastic Transcoder to use for a key checksum.
Decryption Initialization Vector: The Base64 encoded initialization vector that you want Elastic Transcoder to use to decrypt the input.
```

I then do:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo '[KEY]' | xxd -r -p | base64 -i -)
aws kms encrypt --plaintext $OUTPUT --key-id [MY KEY]
```

This returns a `CiphertextBlob` which I can then paste in my `Decryption Parameters -> Decryption Key`.

For the `Decryption Key MD5` I do:

```
echo '[KEY]' | xxd -r -p | md5 | base64 -i -
```

And I paste this at `Decryption Parameters -> Decryption Key MD5`.

The IV is done by:

```
echo '[IV]' | xxd -r -p | base64 -i -
```

Which I then paste at `Decryption Parameters -> Decryption Initialization Vector`.

After completing all these steps and creating the job, AWS comes back with this error:

```
The MD5 hash of the base64-decoded value for ''Encryption:Key'' must equal the base64-decoded value for ''Encryption:KeyMd5''. (Service: AmazonElasticTranscoder; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxxx)
```

---

## Versions

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015

aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.2 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/15.0.0 botocore/1.3.2

xxd -v
xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert

md5 -x
MD5 test suite:
MD5 ("") = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e - verified correct
MD5 ("a") = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661 - verified correct
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72 - verified correct
MD5 ("message digest") = f96b697d7cb7938d525a2f31aaf161d0 - verified correct
MD5 ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b - verified correct
MD5 ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") = d174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f - verified correct
MD5 ("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890") = 57edf4a22be3c955ac49da2e2107b67a - verified correct
MD5 ("MD5 has not yet (2001-09-03) been broken, but sufficient attacks have been made that its security is in some doubt") = b50663f41d44d92171cb9976bc118538 - verified correct

base64 -h       
base64: invalid option -- h
Usage:  base64 [-dhvD] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -D, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

---

## TL;DR

I want to transcode a client-side encrypted file from S3 using Elastic Transcoder but I can't get the keys to work.